# Concentration of centered variable, based on un-centered moments and tails

Tags: inequality, moment-generating-functions, concentration-of-measure, distribution-tails

For a random variable $X$ and positive integers $m,k$ the tail bound is:
$$P(|X|>t) \le \exp(- m t^{2/m} )$$
And for any $k\in\mathbb{N}^{+}$ the moments are given by:
$$E X^{2k+1} = 0$$
$$E X^{2k} \le   (k)^{m k}$$
If we center $X^2$ by $Y:=X^2 - E(X^2)$ , what can be said about the lower its tails? 
$P(|Y|\ge t) = P(|X^2-E(X^2)|\ge t)$?

For the special case that $m=1$ and $m=2$, the tail bound implies that $X$ is sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential respectively, and one can use its machinery to derive some bounds. But I'm not sure what is the best way to derive the tail bounds for this case.

**More context:** this is a followup question on [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337276/concentration-tensor-product-with-a-rank-1-random-tensor-with-sub-gaussian-eleme) MO question. As you can see, the answer derives the tail bound and moment bound mentioned here (discarding some constants). I thought there must be enough information in the moments to prove something about the tails of centered variable, which is why I didn't give the full context (I could be wrong thought?!)

Comment: The claim you make about getting a bound for the right tail being trivial assumes $E(X) \geq 0$.

Comment: While it might not be tight enough for you, you always have Chebyshev's inequality: $\mathbb{P}(X-E(X)\leq -t)\leq\mathbb{P}(\left|X-E(X)\right|\geq t)\leq\sigma^{2}/t^{2}$.

Comment: Also, you should use the $\LaTeX$ `\exp(x)` to get $\exp(x)$.

Comment: oh yes, forgot to mention that the mean is positive, added it to the post

Comment: So, is Chebyshev's bound good enough? What are you trying to accomplish? Is this all the information you know about $X$?

Comment: No Chebyshev is not good enough unfortunately, this is a follow-up question on this MO question, in case more context is needed https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337276/concentration-tensor-product-with-a-rank-1-random-tensor-with-sub-gaussian-eleme

Comment: You can control the mean. By using Jensen's inequality and $\mathbb{E}[|X|] = \int_{t \ge 0} P(|X| \ge t)$ you should get an upper bound of the form $C \Gamma(m/2)$ for some constant $C$ (probably $1/2$? Haven't worked it out). Then for $t \ge 2C \Gamma(m/2),$ you get $P(X \le \mathbb{E}[X] - t) \le P(X \le -t/2)$ gives a similar tail bound as the original. 
Possibly this will not be tight because of the control you have on higher odd moments. I don't quite see how to exploit those.

Comment: Oh it was perhaps misleading to say $t$ is large. In fact I would like to have a decay of the form $P(|X-E(X)|\ge \epsilon E(X)) \le exp(-C \epsilon^2)$